# Canvas containing bitmap size proper adjustment in landscape and portrait mode

Tags: android, android-layout, view, orientation, main-activity

Consider the following image as an example:

[image: Landscape mode]

- **Landscape mode**

In **Landscape mode**, there are 2 sides viz- left side containing `fragment 1` and right side containing `fragment 2`.

The left side (fragment 1) view is fine meaning - buttons are proper, text is coming with right alignment without any overlap/mix with other text.

The right side (fragment 2) view is a chart and its format is not coming correct on the 7' screen. Chart font covers the sides of the grid (on both sides of the grid), chart buttons 
are narrowed to a single letter.

- **Portrait mode**

In **portrait mode**, there is only 1 side viz - right side only containing `fragment 2`.

The 7' screen (tablet device) is small enough in portrait mode that although there is only one fragment (fragment 2) containing chart, but this chart is having same problems as with landscape mode.

Is it possible to reduce the right side chart in landscape mode to get proper view without any text mixing with the chart Or how to do the same for portrait mode?

Any alternatives or ideas?

I found that there is no auto adjustment of views according to orientations although I 
have proper folders-

**res/layout-large/activity_main.xml** and **res/layout-large-land/activity_main.xml**.

where

`res/layout-large/activity_main.xml`- Showing portrait orientation view.

`res/layout-large-land/activity_main.xml`- Showing landscape orientation view.

Comment: Who built the chart? Is it from a library or you made it yourself?

Comment: The white background with the horizontal lines is the image. I decoded it, kept in a canvas then added vertical bar lines according to time and application requirement using `canvas.drawLine`.