# Set bitmap timeline for different DPI, same screen sized devices in landscape orientation

Tags: android, android-layout, screen-resolution

I already read many posts regarding setting the density based layouts but none is matching the criteria as here.

I want to set the top timeline and bottom timeline as seen in [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17103026/canvas-containing-bitmap-size-proper-adjustment-in-landscape-and-portrait-mode) according to differnt DPI values for the same screen size tablet devices in landscape orientation.

See the diagram in the link. The timeline is 1 2 3 4 .. numbers on top of bitmap. They are aligned left in width for tablet 2 due to its higher dpi.

> Tablet 1: 160 DPI 7inch tablet.
>
> Tablet 2: 216 DPI 7inch tablet.

The layout files of `Tablet 1` and `Tablet 2` are placed under `layout-large-land`.
This is causing a shorter timeline for higher density device (Tablet 2).

I adjusted the density for tablet 2 by doing something like:

```
int screenInches = getScreenDimentions();

if(screenInches < 8)
{
DisplayMetrics dm = new DisplayMetrics();

getActivity().getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(dm);                   

// Display device dpi value of Y in pixels
int screenDPIy = (int)dm.ydpi;

if(screenDPIy > 180)
{
  //setting the margins for top and bottom timelines pro-grammatically.
}
```

But this code based idea to set the margins for timelines does not seem appropriate.

What is the standard way of doing that and which folder/layout is considered to be suitable for getting density independent layouts for such scenario?

Is it possible something like `layout-tvdpi-land` and `layout-mdpi-land` to set the layouts
for the above different density devices?

**UPDATE:**

**My layout xml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/chartmain"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#ffffff"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

     <LinearLayout

        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

    <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/relative"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp" >

<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
                android:id="@+id/HView"
                android:layout_width="560dp"
                android:layout_height="255dp"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:layout_marginLeft="160sp"
                android:layout_marginTop="110sp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="80sp">


            </android.support.v4.view.ViewPager>

<TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView2"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/HView"
                android:layout_marginLeft="18dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="90dp"
                android:textSize="14sp"
                android:text="1"
                android:textColor="#000000" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView2"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/HView"
                android:layout_marginLeft="40dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="90dp"
                android:textSize="14sp"
                android:text="2"
                android:textColor="#000000" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView2"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/HView"
                android:layout_marginLeft="62dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="90dp"
                android:textSize="14sp"
                android:text="3"
                android:textColor="#000000" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView2"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/HView"
                android:layout_marginLeft="84dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="90dp"
                android:textSize="14sp"
                android:text="4"
                android:textColor="#000000" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView2"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/HView"
                android:layout_marginLeft="109dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="90dp"
                android:textSize="14sp"
                android:text="5"
                android:textColor="#000000" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView2"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/HView"
                android:layout_marginLeft="132dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="90dp"
                android:textSize="14sp"
                android:text="6"
                android:textColor="#000000" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/topLtTv7"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/HView"
                android:layout_marginLeft="155dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="90dp"
                android:textSize="14sp"
                android:text="7"
                android:textColor="#000000" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/topLtTv8"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/HView"
                android:layout_marginLeft="177dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="90dp"
                android:textSize="14sp"
                android:text="8"
                android:textColor="#000000" />

             <TextView
                android:id="@+id/topLtTv9"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/HView"
                android:layout_marginLeft="200dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="90dp"
                android:textSize="14sp"
                android:text="9"
                android:textColor="#000000" />

                          <TextView
                android:id="@+id/topLtTv10"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/HView"
                android:layout_marginLeft="217dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="90dp"
                android:textSize="14sp"
                android:text="10"
                android:textColor="#000000" />

                 <TextView
                android:id="@+id/topLtTv11"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/HView"
                android:layout_marginLeft="242dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="90dp"
                android:textSize="14sp"
                android:text="11"
                android:textColor="#000000" />

                 <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView2"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/HView"
                android:layout_marginLeft="266dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="90dp"
                android:textSize="12sp"
                android:text="Noon"
                android:textColor="#000000" />

                 <TextView
                android:id="@+id/topRtTv1"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/HView"
                android:layout_marginLeft="296dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="90dp"
                android:textSize="14sp"
                android:text="1"
                android:textColor="#000000" />

                 <TextView
                android:id="@+id/topRtTv2"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/HView"
                android:layout_marginLeft="315dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="90dp"
                android:textSize="14sp"
                android:text="2"
                android:textColor="#000000" />

                  <TextView
                android:id="@+id/topRtTv3"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/HView"
                android:layout_marginLeft="337dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="90dp"
                android:textSize="14sp"
                android:text="3"
                android:textColor="#000000" />

                 <TextView
                android:id="@+id/topRtTv4"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/HView"
                android:layout_marginLeft="359dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="90dp"
                android:textSize="14sp"
                android:text="4"
                android:textColor="#000000" /> 

                  <TextView
                android:id="@+id/topRtTv5"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/HView"
                android:layout_marginLeft="382dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="90dp"
                android:textSize="14sp"
                android:text="5"
                android:textColor="#000000" /> 

                  <TextView
                android:id="@+id/topRtTv6"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/HView"
                android:layout_marginLeft="404dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="90dp"
                android:textSize="14sp"
                android:text="6"
                android:textColor="#000000" />

                    <TextView
                android:id="@+id/topRtTv7"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/HView"
                android:layout_marginLeft="428dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="90dp"
                android:textSize="14sp"
                android:text="7"
                android:textColor="#000000" />

                    <TextView
                android:id="@+id/topRtTv8"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/HView"
                android:layout_marginLeft="450dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="90dp"
                android:textSize="14sp"
                android:text="8"
                android:textColor="#000000" />


            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/topRtTv9"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/HView"
                android:layout_marginLeft="472dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="90dp"
                android:textSize="14sp"
                android:text="9"
                android:textColor="#000000" />


            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/topRtTv10"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/HView"
                android:layout_marginLeft="490dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="90dp"
                android:textSize="14sp"
                android:text="10"
                android:textColor="#000000" />


            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/topRtTv11"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/HView"
                android:layout_marginLeft="515dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="90dp"
                android:textSize="14sp"
                android:text="11"
                android:textColor="#000000" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/totalHoursTop"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/HView"
                android:layout_marginLeft="550dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="90dp"
                android:textSize="14sp"
                android:text="Total Hours"
                android:textColor="#000000" />

        <RelativeLayout/>

        </LinearLayout>

 </LinearLayout>
```

Comment: you're not supposed to set the density of the screen, use dpi and the OS will do the rest

Comment: Can you elaborate in details about dpi way of setting layouts?

Comment: http://developer.android.com/training/multiscreen/screendensities.html

Comment: I already looked that. The problem is my device density falls at ~216 DPI which is tvdpi layout. Can I use something like layout-tvdpi-land for that or something similar for this scenario?

Comment: you don't need a dpi dependent layout file...please add your xml layout file so i could correct it

Comment: gave you the top timeline layout xml. See the update.

Comment: layout_margins must be in dp, not sp

Comment: ok agreed but that isn't the main concern. The idea is to get density independent layouts for the same screen sized devices.

Comment: "This is causing a shorter timeline for higher density device (Tablet 2)"What element is your timeline?what do you mean by shorter?width or height?

Comment: See the diagram in the link. The timeline is `1 2 3 4 ..` numbers on top of bitmap. They are aligned left in width for tablet 2 due to its higher dpi.

Comment: Tablet 1 is showing fine when placed under `layout-large-land`. So I can use `layout-large-land-tvdpi` for tablet 2. Will it auto adjust the width if I do so ? Or I need to do that manually by changing the margins of timelines ?