# Getting end position of the textview and imageview with respect to top of the screen

Tags: android, bitmap, textview, position

I have a bitmap and below it is a time line.

As an example consider the right side layout of the [FIGURE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17103026/canvas-containing-bitmap-size-proper-adjustment-in-landscape-and-portrait-mode).

All the bottom timelines (1, 2, 3...) are in the same height from top.

The timeline is a textview which has fixed layout height and width as it is defined in xml
like timeline 1 is defined as:

```
<TextView
android:id="@+id/textView1"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/HView"
android:layout_marginLeft="18dp"
android:layout_marginTop="345dp"
android:textSize="14sp"
android:text="1"
android:textColor="#000000" />
```

However the bitmap height and width can vary as it is done programatically.

So in certain cases, the bitmap height increases enough to overlap the timeline. In other words,
the vertical position of bitmap increases with respect to the vertical position of the timeline.

**I want to get:**

**1)**  the ended vertical position of bitmap with respect to top of the screen.

**2)**  the ended vertical position of timeline with respect to top of the screen.

I tried to do the following:

```
TextView bottomTimeLine = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.textView1);

bottomTimeLine.getHeight(); //returns 0.

bottomTimeLine.getBottom(); //returns 0.

ImageView img = new ImageView(getActivity());

img.setImageDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.disp_bg));

img.getHeight(); //returns 0.

img.getBottom(); //returns 0.
```

As seen from the code, both the methods, `getHeight()` and `getBottom()` are returning height as 0.

How to get the height (view end position) of both with respect to top of the cell display ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how it can be done:

```
final TextView bottomTimeLine = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.textView1);

 final int[] timelineCoord = new int[2]; 

 final int[] imgCoord = new int[2]; 



ViewTreeObserver vto = bottomTimeLine.getViewTreeObserver();
 vto.addOnGlobalLayoutListener((new OnGlobalLayoutListener() {

    @Override
    public void onGlobalLayout() {


        bottomTimeLine.getLocationOnScreen(timelineCoord);

    Log.d(" bottomTimeLine H ", ""+timelineCoord[1]);

    timelineHeight = timelineCoord[1];
    }
}));


ViewTreeObserver vt1 = img.getViewTreeObserver();
vt1.addOnGlobalLayoutListener((new OnGlobalLayoutListener() {

    @Override
    public void onGlobalLayout() {


        img.getLocationOnScreen(imgCoord);

        imgHeight = imgCoord[1] + img.getHeight();

    Log.d("Img H ", ""+imgHeight);

if(imgHeight < timelineHeight)
{
int heightDiff = imgHeight - timelineHeight ;

heightDiff = heightDiff + 3;

img.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, heightDiff));
}
    }
}));
```

Answer (score 0):

Hope this helps

@Override

protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {
    super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec);

```
int parentWidth = MeasureSpec.getSize(widthMeasureSpec);
int parentHeight = MeasureSpec.getSize(heightMeasureSpec);
this.setMeasuredDimension(
        parentWidth / 2, parentHeight);
```

}