# ClassCastException ViewGroup$LayoutParams cannot be cast to ViewPager$LayoutParams

Tags: android, classcastexception

My initial code line is inside the overridden method `onGlobalLayout()`:

```
img.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, 100));
```

ClassCastException occuring in the overridden method `onGlobalLayout()`-

**Error Log:**

```
09-02 14:25:35.326: E/AndroidRuntime(5187): java.lang.ClassCastException: android.view.ViewGroup$LayoutParams cannot be cast to android.support.v4.view.ViewPager$LayoutParams
09-02 14:25:35.326: E/AndroidRuntime(5187):     at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.onMeasure(ViewPager.java:1319)
09-02 14:25:35.326: E/AndroidRuntime(5187):     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15181)
09-02 14:25:35.326: E/AndroidRuntime(5187):     at android.widget.RelativeLayout.measureChildHorizontal(RelativeLayout.java:617)
09-02 14:25:35.326: E/AndroidRuntime(5187):     at android.widget.RelativeLayout.onMeasure(RelativeLayout.java:399)
09-02 14:25:35.326: E/AndroidRuntime(5187):     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15181)
09-02 14:25:35.326: E/AndroidRuntime(5187):     at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:4814)
09-02 14:25:35.326: E/AndroidRuntime(5187):     at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1390)
```

And when I do the following in order to resolve the above error as indicated in other SO posts:

```
img.setLayoutParams(new ViewPager.LayoutParams(ViewPager.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, 100));
```

Then, I get the compile time error:

```
The constructor ViewPager.LayoutParams(int, int) is undefined
```

ViewPager in xml is defined like:

```
<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
 android:id="@+id/HView"
 android:layout_width="560dp"
 android:layout_height="255dp"
 android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
 android:layout_marginLeft="160sp"
 android:layout_marginTop="110sp"
 android:layout_marginBottom="80sp">
 </android.support.v4.view.ViewPager>
```

Comment: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/view/ViewPager.LayoutParams.html. check the constructors. `public ViewPager.LayoutParams (Context context, AttributeSet attrs)` your params are wrong no constructor that takes int int as param

Comment: check your imports please

Comment: Ok I did checked that but then How to resolve it.

Comment: @LiaPronina - `android.support.v4.view.ViewPager`

Comment: what is this `img`? where is this in XML, whats the parent of this `img`

Comment: try to use ViewGroup instead ViewPager in using LayoutParams

Comment: img - `final ImageView img = new ImageView(getActivity());` Its parent is also dynamically created as: `linearlayout = new LinearLayout(getActivity()); linearlayout.addView(img);`. This is all inside `android.support.v4.view.ViewPager` in the xml.

Comment: Ok try `img.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, 100));`

Comment: I tried all those combinations same error.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Your image already has layout params. Instead of replacing them with a new object (which is of wrong type in this case, `ViewPager` expects them to be `ViewPager.LayoutParams`), you can modify existing layout params like this:

```
ViewGroup.LayoutParams params = img.getLayoutParams();
params.width = ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT;
params.height = 100;
img.requestLayout();
```

Note that unconditionally requesting re-layout in `onGlobalLayout()` can be a bad idea, leading to infinite layout passes. I haven't verified it myself whether this is the case.

Comment: This is causing a loop. I tried to put my code in question just after `onGlobalLayout()` and its working fine but I noticed that my code is getting called before `onGlobalLayout()`. This appears strange just like threads do. So I am bound to put it inside `onGlobalLayout()`.

Comment: Yes - could you clarify why you need to modify the layout in a global layout listener? There's probably a better way. (This answer addresses the class cast exception issue.)

Comment: Because I am trying to get the end position of text view and image view. See my this SO post and my own accepted answer there- `http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18533224/getting-end-position-of-the-textview-and-imageview-with-respect-to-top-of-the-sc`

Comment: See I modified my own answer just now to include the img code there.

Comment: Thanks, I am able to stop the looping by, `view.getViewTreeObserver().removeOnGlobalLayoutListener(this);`.

Comment: Worked perfectly for me!

Comment: the reason why I am trying to create a new object is because .getLayoutParams() is returning null, so what do I do in that case?

Answer (score 0):

**Do this way**

```
img.setLayoutParams(new ViewGroup.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, 100));
```

**UPDATE**

```
 LayoutParams params = img.getLayoutParams();
         params.width = LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT;
         params.height = 100;
         img.setLayoutParams(params);
```

Comment: I already checked that too. Its giving the same exception but this time with the following log: `09-02 14:37:23.953: E/AndroidRuntime(5822): java.lang.ClassCastException: android.view.ViewGroup$LayoutParams cannot be cast to android.support.v4.view.ViewPager$LayoutParams
`

Comment: This is working fine but causing a loop. I tried to put my code in question just after onGlobalLayout() and its working fine but I noticed that my code is getting called before onGlobalLayout(). This appears strange just like threads do. So I am bound to put it inside onGlobalLayout().

Answer (score 0):

You should make sure the `LayoutParam` class you are using is from the correct parent Layout class. And you need to set the LayoutParams of the `ViewGroup` the `ViewPager` is sitting in, as the parent of the `View` that needs to know what size to allocate to the child View.
For example, in your case the `ViewGroup` is a `RelativeLayout`, you need to use the `RelativeLayout.LayoutParams` class.

You can try following:

```
img.setLayoutParams(new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, 100));
```