# Add views dynamically according to seekbar position

Tags: android, seekbar

Is it possible to use the value of the seek bar in android to add a view to the activity?

For example, if the user selects and scrolls to the value of 2 on the seek bar this will have loaded two smaller image views within the same activity

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: I think it is. What did you try?

Comment: I havent tried anything as yet it was just a thought. I was thinking something along the lines of using the: public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progress, boolean fromUser, specifically the progress value to possibly call an extra imageview. I am just unsure how to make sure the image views line up correctly and to actually get it working.

Comment: Check out [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15326403/7972851) answer on how to do that. I think you can use a GridView and set its number of rows or columns according to that. Also check out [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33314550/android-create-grid-with-dynamic-size-in-gridlayout-or-gridview).

Comment: @Brummerly create a layout with seek bar and a listview, create listview items with Image views, when user scrolls and chooses any value, insert some objects into adapter and bingo, you will get that much image views.

Answer (score 3):

I've been working on this question and this is my solution. It might not be perfect so please let me know if there is something to be improved.

[This](https://i.imgur.com/fxWafxz.gifv) is the result.

**1.** Create a new project and [download these sample images](https://developer.android.com/shareables/sample_images.zip). Save the image files into the project's `res/drawable/` directory.

**2.** Open the `res/layout/activity_main.xml` file and insert the following:

**activity_main.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <SeekBar
            android:id="@+id/seekBar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            android:max="10" />
    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

**3.** Open `MainActivity.java` and insert the following code for the `onCreate()` method:

**MainActivity.java**

```
package com.grrigore.dynamicgridview;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.SeekBar;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private int numberOfCurrentImages = 0;
    private int[] images = {
            R.drawable.sample_0,
            R.drawable.sample_1,
            R.drawable.sample_2,
            R.drawable.sample_3,
            R.drawable.sample_4,
            R.drawable.sample_5,
            R.drawable.sample_6,
            R.drawable.sample_7,
            R.drawable.sample_0,
            R.drawable.sample_1,
            R.drawable.sample_2
    };

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        final LinearLayout linearLayout = findViewById(R.id.linearLayout);

        SeekBar seekBar = findViewById(R.id.seekBar);

        seekBar.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(new SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progress, boolean fromUser) {

                for (int i = numberOfCurrentImages; i < progress; i++) {
                    ImageView imageView = new ImageView(MainActivity.this);
                    imageView.setImageResource(images[numberOfCurrentImages]);
                    linearLayout.addView(imageView);
                    numberOfCurrentImages++;
                }

                if (progress == 0 && linearLayout.getChildCount() > 1) {
                    linearLayout.removeViews(1, numberOfCurrentImages);
                    numberOfCurrentImages = 0;
                }

                if (progress < numberOfCurrentImages) {
                    for (int i = numberOfCurrentImages; i > progress; i--) {
                        linearLayout.removeViewAt(i);
                    }
                    numberOfCurrentImages = progress;
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {

            }
        });
    }
}
```

Thanks to:

- [GridView Android](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/gridview)
- [Max's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15326290/get-android-seekbar-value-and-display-it-on-screen/15326403#15326403)
- [Pelanes's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38589845/7972851)
- [laalto's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18569267/classcastexception-viewgrouplayoutparams-cannot-be-cast-to-viewpagerlayoutpara)

Comment: This might not be the solution you are looking for, but I think it provides a good starting point.